# Race condition on virtual machine

Tags: c, unix, virtual-machine, virtualbox, race-condition

I am executing a program which is to demonstrate race condition.
It works fine if the OS is primary boot or dual boot.
But on a virtual machine, it fails to demonstrate race condition.

Virtual machine: Oracle virtual box
  OS: red hat

Code is correct for sure. But for a virtual machine(OS->red hat), it does not work. It simply prints the first process(child) followed by the second process(parent).

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<error.h>

static void charatatime(char *);

int main(void)
{
 pid_t pid;
 if((pid=fork())<0)
 {
  printf("fork error\n");
 }
 else if(pid==0)
  charatatime("output from child\n");
 else
  charatatime("output from parent\n");
 exit(0);
}

static void charatatime(char *str)
{
 char *ptr;
 int c;
 setbuf(stdout,NULL);
 for(ptr=str;(c=*ptr++)!=0;)
  putc(c,stdout);
}
```

What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: Does your race condition rely on multiple CPU cores?

Comment: @RowlandShaw . Yeah my processor is "intel core i3", so yes it is multiple core processor CPU.

Comment: And is your VM running as a multi-core machine?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't know how to check that. Can you specify how to do it?

Comment: It's in Settings -> Processor